# node.js: suppress require()'s echoing of parse errors to stderr

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, require, stderr

node.js 10.26 will rightfully throw an error when you try to require a file that is not valid javascript (or JSON).

My problem is that it **also** outputs to stderr:

*borken.js - know to be broken javascript file*

```
,,>Z>badfile!=-csa&asd;'asdl ds]=}{ADS}DAS:LMFSV'
```

*test.js*

```
try {
    var borken = require('./borken');
} catch (e) {} finally {
    console.log('finally!');
}
```

**Expected**

```
$ node test.js
finally!
```

**Actual**

```
$ node test.js
    /path/to/borken.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { asd;'asdl
                                                                  ^^^^^
finally!
```

The first three lines are output to stderr (running as `node test.js 2> /dev/null` suppresses them).

**Is there any way to get rid of them?**

*What I've done so far:
I debugged while following the source and narrowed down the culprit to:*

[lib/module.js:439](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.26-release/lib/module.js#L439)

```
var compiledWrapper = runInThisContext(wrapper, filename, true);
```

*`runInThisContext` is defined in [lib/vm.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.26-release/lib/vm.js), which unfortunately is a C++ wrapper, so I couldn't really follow what is going on through there.
I guess I'm looking for a magic "don't spam stderr" flag or any knowledge of this being fixed in any latest versions.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this has been fixed in the dev branch (0.11.x) but not in the latest stable (0.10.29)

Github issue: [Syntax errors are printed to stderr, even when wrapped with try/catch #6920](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6920)